# How does "\char`" work?

Tags: symbols, characters, parsing

In LaTeX, you can use `` \char` `` followed by a symbol to get that symbol. For example `` \char`b `` or `` \char`\b `` would just yield the letter `b`.

- Which symbols/letters does that work for? Two cases I've found that yield different symbols are `` \char`{ `` and `` \char`} ``. Is there any sort of reason why those two don't work the way you would think?
- Why does this happen in the first place? Just typing out `` `b `` doesn't give you anything special, so why does it work in the context of a `\char`?
- Why is the backslash ignored in things like `` \char`\_ `` when there's a valid command for `\_`?

I'm still new to LaTeX and it's hard to Google symbol-related stuff like this, so that's why I'm asking here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I recommend Donald Knuth's book "The TeXbook". It gives you complete information on low level TeX commands, and exercises to test your understanding.

Comment: The backtick is explained in the answer below, but note also that `\char` is not a latex command and shouldn't be used in documents, the latex version is `\symbol` which takes a standard latex brace syntax so `\symbol{\`b}` or `\symbol{64}` or whatever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a misunderstanding to attach the left quote to the `\char` command as you do by writing  `` \char` ``.

`\char` expects as argument a number.  With the left quote you are converting the next character or single-character command to its character code (which is a number) *if TeX is currently looking for a number*.

So `` `b `` and `` `\b ``  both give the number 62 in such a context.

You can use this syntax in all places where a number is expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parskip{`b pt}

aba

abc

\end{document}
```

The backslash is needed only for special chars. E.g. `` `\% ``, `` `\{ ``, `` `\} ``, `` `\\ `` but it doesn't harm to add it always. In this context it gives the character "itself".

Comment: Perhaps expand on the backslash rule here? It's a TeX, not a LaTeX, convention ...

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that perhaps surprisingly ``\char`~ ``  is ok, despite the character being active. Or ``\char`: `` with babel-french. (or ``\number\numexpr`~\relax``)

Comment: The backslash is not actually needed for `{` and `}`, unless this would leave unbalanced braces (in a `\def`, for instance).

Comment: @jfbu It works because it's not expanded at all, right? I don't know myself, I'm curious. Also why does ``\char`^`` works but ``\char`^^a`` gives something else hahahhah nah, I'm joking.

Comment: @Manuel yes it is not expanded at all. If you use `"` for hexadecimal input or `'` for octal input in a context where TeX expects a number, expansion happens (and of course expansion happens also without prefix), hence surprise with ` when one has not read the TeXBook closely `;-)`. Edit to my comment above I should have given ``\number`~`` as example. btw, this swallows one space token if it comes next.

Comment: Is there a symbol to int function in latex3? `\char_value_catcode:n{\char``A}` @egreg

Comment: @Erwann ``\int_eval:n {`A}`` if you want the character number. Or ``\char_value_catcode:n {`A}`` if you want the category code. You need to escape special characters. But `\int_eval:n` is not needed where an integer denotation is expected.

Comment: @egreg And from int to char?

Comment: @Erwann please don't use comments under my answer for a conversation with someone else. I get unneeded pings from this. Go to the chat or open a chat room with egreg or ask a proper question.