# What is ` (backtick) used for?

Tags: tex-core

When redefining a category code of accessing a character in Plain-TeX style a backtick is present

```
\catcode`\"=\active
\char`\\
```

What is used for? Is it used in another situations?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402531/how-does-char-work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, I have seen it, but wasn’t that clear for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

backtick followed by a character or single-character command name is one of the tex syntaxes for a number. It is the character code of the character

```
\catcode`\"=\active
\catcode"22=\active
\catcode34=\active
\catcode'42=\active
```

are all the same thing with the number 34 being entered as the character code of `"`, in hex, in decimal and in octal.

This syntax can be used anywhere tex is looking for a number, not specifically for catcodes.

Comment: Is backtick an active character?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Usually it isn't.

Comment: @egreg which category code does it have then?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman It has catcode 12; with another category code, it would be invalid for syntax such as ``\catcode`\_=12``

Comment: @MichaelFraiman The specialness of `\`` does not come just from its category code (as with many other “special” characters), but instead the TeX routines that look for a number are hard-coded to do special stuff after a `\`` token of category code 12. This is similar to the `"` before hexadecimal constants, the `'` before octal constants, and even the decimal point (`.`) inside constants. So you cannot just give another character the special role that `\`` has.